# Series Convergence/Divergence $\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Trying to establish whether $\sum x_n$ for $x_n := \frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$ converges or diverges. Here's what I've done so far:

1) n-th term: $x_n < \frac{n^n}{n^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{n}$, so $\lim(x_n) = 0$; n-th term test inconclusive.

2) quotient test: $$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} &=&\lim \frac{(n+1)^{n+1}/(n+2)^{n+2}}{n^n/(n+1)^{n+1}} \\
&=&\lim \frac{(n+1)^{2n+2}}{(n+2)^{n+2}n^n}\\
&=&\lim \left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)^{n+2}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n}\\
&=& \lim \left(\frac{n+1}{n+2} \frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n}\\
&=& \lim \left(\frac{n^2+2n+1}{n^2+2n}\right)^{n}\\
&=& \lim \left(1+ \frac{1}{2n+n^2}\right)^{n}
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

I am not sure where to go from here. This looks a lot like the classic e limit $\lim (1+1/n)^n$, but it is sufficiently different that I cannot see how to transform it.

3) Root Test:
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim x_n^{1/n} &=& \frac{n}{(n+1)^{1+1/n}} \\
&=& \lim \frac{n}{n+1} \frac{1}{(n+1)^{1/n}}
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

And again stuck here.

Thanks for your help,
Best wishes,

Leon

Comment: Write $\displaystyle x_n={1\over n+1}\cdot {1\over \bigl( 1+{1\over n}\bigr)^n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not hard to see that $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{-n}> \frac{1}{e}$, so $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{-n}\frac{1}{n+1}>\frac{1}{e}\frac{1}{n+1}$. But $\sum \frac{1}{e}\frac{1}{n+1}$ diverges so the original series diverges too.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks (and thanks to the others as well!) - that was exactly the rearrangement of terms I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$x_n=\frac1{n+1}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{-n}\sim_\infty\frac{e^{-1}}{n}$$
and the harmonic series $\sum\frac1n$ is divergent. Conclude.

Comment: Short and sweet!

Answer (score 2):

From the simple inequality $1+u \leq e^u$,$$
\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}} = \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n} \frac{1}{n+1} \geq\frac{e^{-1}}{n+1}
$$
and we conclude that the series diverges by comparison with the harmonic series.